# Export DataTable object to Excel sheet long string formatting issue

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, datatable

I have some troubles when I export a `DataTable` to Excel, I have a cell that contains max. 20 characters as string. When I get the Excel file, it shows like scientific format, but I want to show all the string value inside cell.

[image]

Here is my code used to fill the DataRows and DataColumns:

```
Dim sheet As New System.Data.DataTable("teste")
        sheet.Columns.Add("DDebut")
        sheet.Columns.Add("Nbrecheance")
        Dim col As DataColumn = New DataColumn(" Reference ", GetType(String))
        col.MaxLength = 25
        sheet.Columns.Add(col)

sheet.Rows.Add(line.CCP_acct, line.ccp_cle, line.nom, line.prenom, line.mt_prelev, Param.ccp_abc, Param.key_abc, date_prelev, line.nbr_ech, Format(id_ref))
```

Then the code used to export DataTable to excel

```
Dim sheet As New DataTable
        Dim export_data As New DataBaseManager
        sheet = export_data.Exportallertoexcel(id)
        Dim file_name As String = New String("reportprelevemntN°" + id.ToString() + ".xls")
        Dim grid As New GridView
        grid.DataSource = sheet
        grid.DataBind()

        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file_name)
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
        Response.Charset = ""
        Dim sw As New StringWriter
        Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        grid.RenderControl(htw)

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```

My issue is with last column `Reference`, I tried using `FormatNumber` and adding styles in Format method like "#" and "0" without any result.

I think the problem is related with length of string, because I had others value under 10 characters it shown correctly, any way to set cell width or use an other class to export to Excel.

Comment: This happens because Excel tries to infer the type from the value of the cell.  Since you are putting in a twenty numeric digits, it's assuming that you want a number type.  you are seeing scientific notation because the number is so long.  If you widen the cell, you should see the original number.  You can force the cell to be text by adding a leading ' to the value.  That tells Excel you want the value interpreted as text.

Comment: and how to do it with DataTable Object ?